# why the update query does not update the date in Mysql database

Tags: java, mysql

I found a problem when updating the data in the database. The log shows update successfully, but the data in the database does not change. this happens sometimes, not frequently, like 1 of 200.

below is the code:

```
public void updateRecharge(String serial_num, String msg, String succ_amout, String datetime) {
    try {
        con = open();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.writeLog(serial_num, datetime, "fail to update: " + e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    String area = new JudgeTidField().checkTidField(serial_num)[1];
    String table = new JudgeTidField().table(area);

    String query = "update " + table + " set Recharge_state=?, Recharge_money=?, Recharge_record_date=? where Serial_number='" + serial_num + "';";

    try {   
        preState = con.prepareStatement(query);
        preState.setString(1, msg);
        preState.setFloat(2, Float.valueOf(succ_amout));
        preState.setString(3, datetime);
        preState.executeUpdate();

        log.writeLog(serial_num, datetime, "success to update");
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
        log.writeLog(serial_num, datetime, "fail to update: " + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        try {
            preState.close();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I check the log, it shows "success to update", but the data does not change. what kind of problem cause this happening?

Comment: What is the SQL type of the Recharge_record_date column?

Comment: 1- You should use a `?` for `serial_num` like the other parameters; 2- `preState.executeUpdate();` returns a `int` value representing the number of the rows updated, you might want to check it

Comment: @Steve C the type is datetime

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @MadProgrammer you should use parameter replacement for the serialNum and check the return value from executeUpdate.

Additionally, I would use [java.text.DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) to convert `datetime` into a java.util.Date and call [java.sql.PreparedStatement.setDate(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setDate(int,%20java.sql.Date)) to apply it to `preState`. This will trap any date format problems early.

Also if any parameters are null then you must explicitly call [java.sql.PreparedStatement.setNull(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setNull(int,%20int))